# Is there a reason why this .all? isn't working right?

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe

```
def won?
        WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |wins|
            if wins.all?{|win_nums| @board[win_nums] = "X"}
                wins
            elsif wins.all?{|win_nums| @board[win_nums] = "O"}
                wins
            end
        end
        false
    end
```

So, I am trying to get this code to run where `WIN_COMBINATIONS` is a nested array containing, well, winning combos for tic tac toe on an array board. I figured I could just use the `.all?` method and return whichever combo scored first but for some reason it keeps failing with the following:

> expected a collection that can be converted to an array with “#to_ary”
> or “#to_a

TOTALLY STUMPED!! Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `any?` rather than `all?`? Please edit to show `WIN_COMBINATIONS` (or is it `WINNING_COMBINATIONS`?).

Comment: Hey there, are you sure that you want @board[win_nums] = "X" instead of @board[win_nums] == "X", also here are the docs for all?, maybe that helps too: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F

Comment: You probably also want `return wins` instead of just `wins` – otherwise your method will always return `false`. Another option is `WIN_COMBINATIONS.find { ... }` to find the first combo matching your criteria.

Comment: Try this: `def won?; WIN_COMBINATIONS.any? { |win| ['X', 'O'].include?(win.map { |cell| @board[cell] }.uniq) }; end`.

Comment: "keeps failing" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @Stefan WOW!!!! Thank you for this response, it was the missing explicit return along with “==“ instead of “=“. Big thank you to those who helped !!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for the response  I got it to work with .all? by explicitly returning wins & changing the “=“s to “==“

Comment: @JörgWMittag Totally understandable my man, I edited my question with more detail but thankfully I got it to work. Thank you for the input !!

Comment: @r4cc00n Definitely needed those “==“s along with an explicit return for wins. Thank you for the advice, it really means a lot considering how long I spent fiddling with this !!

Comment: happy to help you @NateHains

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. you use `@board[win_nums] = ...` which is *assignment* – you  want `==`, i.e. *comparison*
2. you never return anything but `false`, so  even if  your conditions are met,  you don't return the corresponding `wins`  combination

To fix your code:

```
def won?
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |wins|
    if wins.all? { |win_nums| @board[win_nums] == "X" }
      return wins
    elsif wins.all? { |win_nums| @board[win_nums] == "O" }
      return wins
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Instead fetching each value in `wins` from `@board` separately, you could use [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#values_at-method) to fetch all 3 values at once:

```
def won?
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |wins|
    if @board.values_at(*wins).all?('X')
      return wins
    elsif @board.values_at(*wins).all?('O')
      return wins
    end
  end
  false
end
```

If you're wondering about the splash operator `*` – it turns the `wins` array into an argument list so  `values_at(*[0, 1, 2])` becomes `values_at(0, 1, 2)`

We can remove some duplication from the above code by storing the result from `values_at` in a variable. We can  also use `||` to combine both conditions:

```
def won?
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |wins|
    values = @board.values_at(*wins) 
    return wins if values.all?('X') || values.all?('O')
  end
  false
end
```

Finally, there's [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#find-method) which handles the `return` logic for us:

```
def won?
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.find do |wins|
    values = @board.values_at(*wins)
    values.all?('X') || values.all?('O') 
  end
end
```

Note that `find` returns `nil` instead of `false` to indicate "no match" but since both are *falsey* this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the time to educate me Stefan, this was really helpful!